# Change CSS with Javascript ".modalDialog > div {}"

Tags: javascript, css

I have a Modal Layer with css. When I open the modal layer with Javascript I want to change the width:400px of it to anything else. How can I do it?

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div>
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
<video width="640" height="480" id="notes_video" controls fullscreen>
<source src="video/Opening.webm" type="video/webm">
<track kind="subtitles" src="opening.vtt" srclang="de"></track>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS-Code:

```
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".modalDialog").css("width", "10px");
```